# "Immediately, David and Adan skedaddle."

Tags: word-usage

> John takes a gun. Immediately, David and Adan skedaddle from the place.

> John takes a gun. Immediately, David and Adan skedaddle.

> John takes a gun. Immediately, David and Adan skedaddle from that place.

I never used this word before. I want to keep the sentence short as the second one, but I'm not sure whether that sentence is valid.

Comment: Who are these people and in what year are they fleeing?

Comment: @StoneyB These people are in the current young generation.

Comment: I think it unlikely that *skedaddle* would be properly used in that context. It's never been formal English, and as far as I know it vanished from contemporary slang in the 50s.

Comment: @StoneyB: It's "dated", sure. As are alternatives like *legged it, scrammed, scarpered, high-tailed it, vamoosed*. But there are probably still some people who use them "naturally", and lots of people will use them "facetiously, self-consciously". I bet sometime in the last decade I've said or heard *"We lit outta there!"* or similar, but so far as I know people haven't *lit* anywhere for real since [Huckleberry Finn](http://www.helium.com/items/1317043-review-and-plot-of-mark-twain-huckleberry-finn-sequel-where-huck-and-tom-light-out-for-the-territory) *lit out for the territory*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Google Ngrams says *lit out* peaked in the 1940s. But folks was writing a lotta Westerns in them days.

Comment: @FumbleFingers In google Ngrams I see skedaddle in second most used even in 2000. Check here > http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=skedaddle%2Cscarper%2Cscram%2Cvamoose&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: @ T2E: I'm not sure that's a useful way to establish "currency". If you [compare "I skedaddled" vs "I lit out"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+skedaddled%2CI+lit+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) you'll see that the former virtually flatlines again the latter. I do not think you'll find many people who would naturally and unselfconsciously use either expression, but I think most would agree that of the two, *to light out* is the more "dated".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second sentence is fine. In fact I'd say it's the best of the three. It's implicit that they're from their current location.

However I'd consider carefully whether you actually want to use the word. It's very informal, bordering on slang, and is rarely used in written English.

Comment: +1 It's not only informal, it's dated; it was mostly replaced by *scram* in the 1930s; in the 50s and 60s we regarded it as peculiar to Westerns and rural comedies, and used it only jocularly and ironically. The equivalent term in my generation was *haul ass*; I don't know what it is now.

Comment: @Nigel Harper  So what is better word used by the current generation? flee?

Comment: @StoneyB So what is better word used by the current generation? flee?

Comment: @StoneyB It's probably *got the hell out of there*, but we're still talking highly informal. I'd advise OP to just use *fled*.

Comment: @T2E "flee" or simply "run away" would be good choices which are neither dated nor informal.

Comment: @T2E: It doesn't always imply *hasty* departure, but a lot of people now say things like ["We gotta bounce!"](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/game/doctorsadvocate.html), and sometimes (as there) they're clearly in a hurry.

Comment: @WendiKidd Flee doesn't mean hasty departure. I'm looking for a word which can be used in hasty departure when get scared.

Comment: @NigelHarper So If I write "David and Adan flee", is correct? Can a verb stand alone at the end of a sentence like this?

Comment: @T2E That sentence is fine. A subject and a verb together make a simple but complete sentence. Such sentences are quite rarely seen but sometimes that's all you need.

Comment: "got out of there", "got themselves out of there", "left posthaste", "disappeared", "scrambled for the exits", "scampered away", "bounced", "vanished from the room".  Still, I'm not sure if I would recount this story in the present tense, to me 'they skedaddled' is much more common than "they skedaddle".